# Onscreen keyboard and tablet mode Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: keyboard, laptop, touchscreen, 19.04

I've recently purchased an HP Envy x360 2-in-1 laptop and installed Ubuntu 19.04 in it.

While using it, I realized that instead of clicking on things, I could just tap on my screen, which is very convenient, but when I tap on text fields, the onscreen keyboard shows up.

Also, when I fold the laptop to enter tablet mode, the actual keyboard is still on use, making the tablet mode incredibly hard to use.

Ideally, I would like:

1. The onscreen keyboard to never show up when I don't have the laptop folded in tablet mode
2. The onscreen keyboard showing up as it does now when it is folded
3. The actual keyboard to be disabled when it is folded

What I have found so far hasn't been very helpful in achieving the above. Can someone please help me?

Thanks